# Add tapGesture to tableView then can not perform tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

As we know, we use the below code can `endEditing` the searchBar's firstResponder, but if there is a scrollView or tableView, the effect is different.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I add the `tapGesture` to tableView, so I can `endEditing` the searchBar's firstResponder.

But after add the `tapGesture` to my tableView, the tableView's `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function will not work any more.

How can I solve the issue?

---

**Addition**

My useful code is below:

```
let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapTableView))
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


func tapTableView() {

    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Unless you check the view it is touching it will override all touches, instead you could consider using the keyboardDismiss on tableview that is built in such as .interactive

Comment: @SeanLintern88 How do you mean use kwyboardDismiss on tableView ?

Answer (score 0):

add the tapGesture on the view not on tableView

```
let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapTableView))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: and you change ' self.searchBar.endEditing(true)' this to this ' self.view.endEditing(true)'

Comment: it is the same brother,  and this comment is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on your table view add

```
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

You can change `.onDrag` to `.interactive` too. Remove the Touches began.

Edit: From apple docs

```
case none
    The keyboard does not get dismissed with a drag.
case onDrag
    The keyboard is dismissed when a drag begins.
case interactive
    The keyboard follows the dragging touch offscreen, and can be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss.
```

Comment: Could you give more detail information? I set `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag` or `. interactive ` , there is no effect , is somewhere goes wrong ?